# Is LocaleContextHolder safe in service layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

According to official doc, LocaleContextHolder is:

> Simple holder class that associates a LocaleContext instance with the current thread.

So it is tied to current `thread`, but is this talking about the `Thread` thread or a thread of current request.

Apologize if it is a dumb question, I am not sure a LocaleContextHolder is tied to a HTTP session or something so that it is safe to use in any service layer class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look at the source code for `LocaleContextHolder`, you will notice it has a `ThreadLocal` variable (it has two actually)

```
private static final ThreadLocal<LocaleContext> localeContextHolder =
        new NamedThreadLocal<LocaleContext>("Locale context");
```

You can read about what a `ThreadLocal` is but for our sake, consider it a data structure that maps the ID of the current executing thread to an object of its generic type, `LocaleContext` here.

A Servlet container has a pool of threads it uses to handle client requests. When a request comes in, it will extract one of these threads and execute your servlet's `service()` method. With Spring, this results in `DispatcherServlet` executing and your `@Controller`'s handler method being called. This all happens in that original `Thread` the servlet container chose.

So when your `@Service` class' method gets called, you're still in that same thread.

The `ThreadLocal` in `LocaleContextHolder` is `set()` at some point early on in request processing, in `FrameworkServlet` (which is the parent type of `DispatcherServlet`) method `initContextHolders()` called by `processRequest()` in each of `doGet()`, `doPost()`, etc. methods. The `Locale` is built from the `HttpServletRequest` with its `getLocale()` method.

Comment: Very good explanations, save me a lot of reading to get such essence. One more question is, as the container holds a pool of thread, one `localeContextHolder` per thread so does that mean each `thread` support a `DispatchServlet` and each `dispatchServet` holds a `localeContexHolder`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dreamer Not exactly. Each thread will have a `LocaleContext` (if it is `set()` on the `ThreadLocal`). The `Thread` spawned by the servlet container has a `run()` method that has a reference to your `DispatcherServlet` which it uses to call methods with the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletREsponse` objects. The `DispatcherServlet` _dispatches_ to your `@Controller` methods. The `localeContexHolder` is a `static` field of the `LocaleContexHolder` class.